# Selecting a distinct value and the sum of times it shows up in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing table with millions of entries (growing) that consists of:

```
userid|name|etc...

1   frank    ...
1   frank    ...
2   joe      ...
5   sam      ...
1   franky   ...
```

What I need to do is return a table of:

```
place|name|total

1   franky   3
2   sam      1
3   joe      1
```

Where total is the SUM(userid = the distinct userid).

Currently I'm doing a query to `SELECT DISTINCT userid from table` and then foreach returned value in php, I'm doing another query to return the name and sum(userid = userid).

As you can assume, this is very taxing and takes a long time now with all of the values. Is there any way to speed this up by doing 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need

```
SELECT  @a:=@a+1 AS `place`, name, COUNT(userid) AS `total`
FROM `your_table`, (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   userid, COUNT(*)
FROM     some_table
GROUP BY userid
```